# Update value from table if/else

Tags: php, sql, database

change status vice versa when active then change status in db as inactive

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE profile SET status='active' WHERE status='inactive' AND id =$id")
or die(mysql_error()); 

header("Location: admin-members.php");
}
else{
header("Location: admin-members.php");
}
```

*this is a working code but i wanted it to work both ways. when i click **inactive** it would change it **active** and vise versa. i tried it with case too but no luck*

?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe you only want to filter it by `$sid` and use `CASE` to toggle the value of `status`

```
UPDATE profile 
SET status = (CASE WHEN status = 'active' THEN 'inactive' ELSE 'active' END)
WHERE id = $id
```

Comment: oh WOW! It worked! thank you so much. I've been stuck with this thing for weeks. again, thanks John!

Answer (score 0):

```
    $getStatus =mysql_query(" select status from profile where id =$id") 
or     die(mysql_error());
    $stat = mysql_fetch_assoc($getStatus);
    if($stat['status']== 'inactive')
    {
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE profile SET status='active' AND id =$id");
    }
    elseif($stat['status']== 'active')
    {
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE profile SET status='inactive' id =$id");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in your status as a $_GET variable too, and check that it is an acceptable value.

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && in_array($_GET['status'],array('active','inactive')))
{
$id = $_GET['id'];
$status = $_GET['status'];
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE profile SET status='$status' WHERE id =$id")
or die(mysql_error()); 

header("Location: admin-members.php");
}
else{
header("Location: admin-members.php");
}
```

*From here you might want to parameterise your query to safeguard against SQL injection too.

Comment: right. i really have to consider the security as well. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If active and inactive are all the available options, I mean if there isn't any third option, John Woo's suggestion will do it. Yet here's another approach.

```
UPDATE `profile`
SET `status` = IF(`status`='active','inactive','active')
WHERE `id` = $id
```

If there is a third option then you might want to add that in your when clause:

```
WHERE `id` = $id AND `status` IN ('active','inactive')
```

or

```
WHERE `id` = $id AND (`status`='active' OR `status`='inactive')
```